# finding, parsing and validating email addresses

Tags: string, go

```
 import "fmt"

func main() {
    email := "learning@gmail.com"
    atTrue := false
    s := ""
    for i := 0; i < len(email); i++ {
        if atTrue {
            s += string(email[i])
        }
        if string(email[i]) == "@" {
            atTrue = true
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

current output: `gmail.com`

expect output: Domain: `gmail` and TLD: `com`

How to indicate looping from certain string to certain string?

Comment: You're better off using a library that already knows how to properly parse an email address than trying to re-invent the wheel. Incidentally, you should avoid appending to a string in a loop, because it's not great for performance (esp. if the input is provided by potentially malicious users). See [`strings.Builder`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Builder).

Comment: The question is unclear, though. Are you trying to extract the eTLD from the email address's domain?

Comment: If so, there is a [`golang.org/x/net.publicsuffix` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix) that's right up your alley. The only downside is that it's infrequently updated and doesn't stay abreast of the changes in the Public Suffix list. https://go.dev/play/p/ry8sONLNI1Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strings.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) function

```
    email := "learning@gmail.com"
    split := strings.Split(email, "@")
    split = strings.Split(split[1], ".")
    fmt.Println("Domain:", split[0])
    fmt.Println("TLD:", split[1])
```

optionally you can validate an email string with [mail.ParseAddress](https://pkg.go.dev/net/mail#ParseAddress) function

```
    email := "learning@gmail.com"
    addr, err := mail.ParseAddress(email)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

> what if the TLD goes like this co.id, does the output still co.id ? –
> @zacharyy

simply try to find the first `index` of `.` ([strings.Index](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Index)) and use one to separate the string

```
    email := "learning@gmail.co.id"
    split := strings.Split(email, "@")
    index := strings.Index(split[1], ".")
    fmt.Println("Domain:", split[1][:index])
    fmt.Println("TLD:", split[1][index+1:])
```

or use [regexp.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.Split) function

```
    email := "learning@gmail.co.id"
    split := strings.Split(email, "@")
    split = regexp.MustCompile("[.]").
        Split(split[1], 2)
    fmt.Println("Domain:", split[0])
    fmt.Println("TLD:", split[1])
```

or [strings.SplitN](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#SplitN)

```
    email := "learning@gmail.co.id"
    split := strings.Split(email, "@")
    split = strings.SplitN(split[1], ".", 2)
    fmt.Println("Domain:", split[0])
    fmt.Println("TLD:", split[1])
```

or [strings.Cut](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Cut)

```
    _, host, found := strings.Cut(email, "@")
    if !found {
        t.Fatal("fail cut to host (Domain + TLD)")
    }
    domain, tld, found := strings.Cut(host, ".")
    if !found {
        t.Fatal("fail cut to Domain and TLD")
    }
    fmt.Println("Domain:", domain)
    fmt.Println("TLD:", tld)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/K7f2Hgjb-80)</kbd>

**Benchmarks**

```
    const (
        quantity   = 10000
        userLength = 10
        domain     = "gmail.com"
    )
    var (
        letterRunes = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        emails      = make([]string, 0, quantity)
        seeded      = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixMilli()))
    )

    for i := 0; i < quantity; i++ {
        user := make([]rune, userLength)
        for i := range user {
            user[i] = letterRunes[seeded.Intn(len(letterRunes))]
        }
        emails = append(emails, fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s", string(user), domain))
    }

    b.Run("strings.Split", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        var domain, tld string
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for _, email := range emails {
                domain, tld = stringsSplit(email)
            }
        }
        _, _ = domain, tld
    })
    b.Run("strings.SplitN", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        var domain, tld string
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for _, email := range emails {
                domain, tld = stringsSplitN(email)
            }
        }
        _, _ = domain, tld
    })
    b.Run("strings.Index+strings.Split", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        var domain, tld string
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for _, email := range emails {
                domain, tld = stringsIndexAndStringsSplit(email)
            }
        }
        _, _ = domain, tld
    })
    b.Run("regexp.Split", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        var domain, tld string
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for _, email := range emails {
                domain, tld = regexpSplit(email)
            }
        }
        _, _ = domain, tld
    })
    b.Run("strings.Cut", func(b *testing.B) {
        b.ReportAllocs()
        b.ResetTimer()
        var domain, tld string
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            for _, email := range emails {
                domain, tld = stringsCut(email)
            }
        }
        _, _ = domain, tld
    })
```

```
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Benchmark
Benchmark/strings.Split
Benchmark/strings.Split-12                  752    1563851 ns/op      640002 B/op      20000 allocs/op
Benchmark/strings.SplitN
Benchmark/strings.SplitN-12                 805    1463329 ns/op      640003 B/op      20000 allocs/op
Benchmark/strings.Index+strings.Split
Benchmark/strings.Index+strings.Split-12   1416     858783 ns/op      320000 B/op      10000 allocs/op
Benchmark/regexp.Split
Benchmark/regexp.Split-12                    85   14605240 ns/op    11088513 B/op     160024 allocs/op
Benchmark/strings.Cut
Benchmark/strings.Cut-12                   6597     180579 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```